# Graph disappears in core plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-plot

In my app I am using core plot. Everything is fine as below
[image: Graph with values].

On pressing next or prev button, core plot shows values of next or previous 7 days. When I press the button many times say 142 times, graph disappears and core plot only shows x and y labels as shown below.[image: Error].
And on tapping more app crashes. How can I fix my issue? Please help. Also in the debug area it shows

> malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
>   *** error: can't allocate region securely
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

It also gives bad access at [image: DateFormatter]

I don't know where my issue is.My code for generating graph is...

```
- (void)generateLayout
{

//Create graph from theme
self.graph                               = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
self.graph = (CPTXYGraph *)[theme newGraph];

//graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:183.0/255.0 green:206.0/255.0 blue:227.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];


//[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
self.hostedGraph                         = self.graph;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder   = NO;
self.graph.paddingLeft                   = 0.0f;
self.graph.paddingTop                    = 0.0f;
self.graph.paddingRight                  = 0.0f;
self.graph.paddingBottom                 = 0.0f;

CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle    = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
borderLineStyle.lineColor               = [CPTColor clearColor];
borderLineStyle.lineWidth               = 2.0f;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle     = borderLineStyle;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop          = 10.0;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight        = 10.0;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom       = 30.0;
self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft         = 50.0;

//Add plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace       = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.delegate              = self;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// Here We Can Set The Range Of Y Axis////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
plotSpace.yRange    = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(greaterGlass * sets.count)];

//plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(greaterGlass * sets.count)];

plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1)
                                                               length:CPTDecimalFromInt(8)];

//Grid line styles
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth            = 2.75;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor            = [[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:113.0/255.0 green:91.0/255.0 blue:84.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0];
CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth            = 0.50;
minorGridLineStyle.lineColor            = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

majorGridLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1], [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5], nil];

//Axes
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.graph.axisSet;

//X axis
CPTXYAxis *x                    = axisSet.xAxis;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal   = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
x.majorIntervalLength           = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
x.minorTicksPerInterval         = 0;
x.labelingPolicy                = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.majorGridLineStyle            = majorGridLineStyle;
x.axisConstraints               = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

//X labels
int labelLocations = 0;


//NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[dates count]];
//for (NSString *day in dates)
for(int couter=0; couter<[dates count]; couter++)
{
    NSString *day = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dates objectAtIndex:couter]];
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:day textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation   = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:labelLocations] decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset         = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    //newLabel.rotation       = M_PI / 4;
    [customXLabels addObject:newLabel];
    labelLocations++;
    [newLabel release];
}

x.axisLabels                    = [NSSet setWithArray:customXLabels];

//Y axis
CPTXYAxis *y            = axisSet.yAxis;

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] ;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ComicSansMS-Bold" size:12.0];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.text = @"Number of Glasses";

y.title                 = label.text;
y.titleOffset           = 50.0f;
y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.majorGridLineStyle    = majorGridLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle    = minorGridLineStyle;
y.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

//Create a bar line style
CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle   = [[[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
barLineStyle.lineWidth              = 1.0;
barLineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
whiteTextStyle.color                = [CPTColor whiteColor];

//Plot
BOOL firstPlot = YES;
for (NSString *set in [[sets allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]) {
    //UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:87.0/255.0 green:181.0/255.0 blue:229.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    //CPTColor *mineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:160 green:97 blue:5 alpha:1];
    CPTBarPlot *plot        = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    plot.lineStyle          = barLineStyle;
    CGColorRef color        = ((UIColor *)[sets objectForKey:set]).CGColor;

    //plot.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color]];

    plot.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:111.0/255.0 green:164.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

    if (firstPlot) {
        plot.barBasesVary   = NO;
        firstPlot           = NO;
    } else {
        plot.barBasesVary   = YES;
    }
    plot.barWidth           = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.5f);
    plot.barsAreHorizontal  = NO;
    plot.dataSource         = self;
    plot.identifier         = set;
    [self.graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
}

}
```

Comment: The core plot values not loading when your tapped to the next button, it shows the default values on Y-axis. date format  the myDateString comes nil , so its gives BAD_ACCESS, try to display NSLOG this method

Comment: I checked. Its giving correct values. On Iphone it crashes after pressing button 142 times and on Ipad it crashes after 28 times.

Comment: It sounds like the app is running out of memory. What happens when you press the *Next* or *Prev* buttons? Are you just reloading the plot data with the new values or does it create a whole new graph each time? Are you keeping the old data around in the datasource or replacing it with the new data?

Comment: On every button press -(void)generateLayout is being called. So every time it creates a new self.graph.

Comment: My bar graph disppears when i switch my app to background and then again comes back to foreground. Plz help